# Error CORS en Angular 4

Tags: angular, api, cors

Tengo un proyecto de Angular 4 y una API en .NET, en la API tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
//http://localhost:40406/api/shoppingCartFunctions/putProductoManual?codigo_Sku=123&codCliente=111

    [HttpPut, Route("api/shoppingCartFunctions/putProductoManual")]
    public Shopping_Cart PutProductoManual(String codigo_Sku, String codCliente, String userName)
    {
        try
        {
            Shopping_Cart result = Shopping_Cart_Functions.Instance.Add_ProductoManual(codigo_Sku, codCliente, userName);
            return result;//.Formatted();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.RegisterLog(this.ToString(), ex.Message, ex, EventTypeP3W.Error);
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Dentro del código de Angular tengo este método:

```
addProduct(order, productSku) {
        let user = this.loginService.getLoggedUser();
        const body = JSON.stringify(order); 
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        
        let _order = new OrderPut(
            productSku,
            user.cedula === 0 ? this.loginService.getCurrentClient() : user.cedula.toString(),
            user.userName
        );        

        let codCliente;
        
        if (user.cedula === 0)
        {
            codCliente = this.loginService.getCurrentClient();
        }
        else {
            codCliente = user.cedula
        }    
        return this.http.put('http://localhost:40406/api/shoppingCartFunctions/putProductoManual?codigo_Sku=' + _order.codigo_Sku + '&codCliente=' + codCliente +'&userName=' + _order.userName,body)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let orderPutResponse = response.json();                

                return orderPutResponse;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
```

Cuando me voy a la pagina, me obtengo un 405:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar a encontrar por que se da este error y como se puede resolver? (Los demas métodos están iguales que este).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En teoria tienes un error en la forma en que envias los datos a tu api REST
Por defecto el metodo Edit del controlador API en .Net espera solo el Id por ruta y el objeto a editar se pasa en el cuerpo. En tu caso estas pasando todos los parametros por la ruta y por lo tanto tu api no encuentra una Accion que tome todos esos params

Tu backend debe esperar algo similar a esto

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody] Product model)
    {
       ....
    }
```

en tu cliente deberias pasar el objeto en el cuerpo de la peticion, http.put() acepta el objeto como parametro, puedes consultar la doc de Angular HttpClient aqui https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put